# Compare performance of using LocalBroadcastManager and Otto

Tags: android, otto, localbroadcastmanager

I'm trying to compare performance of using `LocalBroadcastManager` and `Otto` in Android. As I know, Otto is using annotation and Java reflection, so it may have some impacts on performance. Can someone suggest me something to do to measure performance of these two ways? Which drain the battery?

Answer (score 2):

This is already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22871206/otto-vs-localbroadcast) and you can find a performance comparison between Otto and EventBus (another alternative) [here](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/blob/master/COMPARISON.md)

My guess it Otto and EventBus are probably as fast or faster than LBM :)